# How to generate a sequence of monthly dates from a data frame in R?

Tags: r, date, runtime-error, sequence, lubridate

Consider the following data frame (df):

```
"id"    "date_start"    "date_end"
 a       2012-03-11     2012-03-27
 a       2012-05-17     2012-07-21
 a       2012-06-09     2012-08-18
 b       2015-06-21     2015-07-12
 b       2015-06-27     2015-08-04
 b       2015-07-02     2015-08-01
 c       2017-10-11     2017-11-08
 c       2017-11-27     2017-12-15
 c       2017-01-02     2018-02-03
```

I am trying to create a new data frame with sequences of monthly dates, starting one month prior to the minimum value of "date_start" for each group in "id". The sequence also only includes dates from the first day of a month and ends at the maximum value of "date-end" for each group in "id".

This is a reproducible example for my data frame:

```
library(lubridate)

id <- c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c")
df <- data.frame(id)
df$date_start <- as.Date(c("2012-03-11", "2012-05-17","2012-06-09", "2015-06-21", "2015-06-27","2015-07-02", "2017-10-11", "2017-11-27","2018-01-02"))
df$date_end <- as.Date(c("2012-03-27", "2012-07-21","2012-08-18", "2015-07-12", "2015-08-04","2015-08-012", "2017-11-08", "2017-12-15","2018-02-03"))
```

What I have tried to do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(Desctools)
library(timeDate)

df2 <- df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   summarize(start= floor_date(AddMonths(min(date_start),-1), "month"),end=max(date_end)) %>%
   do(data.frame(id=.$id, date=seq(.$start,.$end,by="1 month")))
```

The code works perfectly fine for an ungrouped data frame. Somehow, with the grouping by "id" it throws an error message:

```
Error in seq.default(.$date_start, .$date_end, by = "1 month") : 
'from' must be of length 1
```

This is how the desired output looks like for the data frame given above:

```
"id"       "date"    
 a       2012-02-01     
 a       2012-03-01     
 a       2012-04-01     
 a       2012-05-01    
 a       2012-06-01     
 a       2012-07-01     
 a       2012-08-01         
 b       2015-05-01 
 b       2015-06-01 
 b       2015-07-01
 b       2015-08-01  
 c       2017-09-01 
 c       2017-10-01 
 c       2017-11-01
 c       2017-12-01
 c       2018-01-01
 c       2018-02-01
```

Is there a way to alter the code to function with a grouped data frame? Is there an altogether different approach for this operation?

Comment: I did not know that. I will edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Use `as.yearmon` to convert to year/month.  Note that yearmon objects are represented internally as year + fraction where fraction is 0 for January, 1/12 for February, 2/12 for March and so on.  Then use `as.Date` to convert that to Date class.  `do` allows the group to change size.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  do( data.frame(month = as.Date(seq(as.yearmon(min(.$date_start)) - 1/12,
                                     as.yearmon(max(.$date_end)), 
                                     1/12) ))) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 17 x 2
   id    month     
   <fct> <date>    
 1 a     2012-02-01
 2 a     2012-03-01
 3 a     2012-04-01
 4 a     2012-05-01
 5 a     2012-06-01
 6 a     2012-07-01
 7 a     2012-08-01
 8 b     2015-05-01
 9 b     2015-06-01
10 b     2015-07-01
11 b     2015-08-01
12 c     2017-09-01
13 c     2017-10-01
14 c     2017-11-01
15 c     2017-12-01
16 c     2018-01-01
17 c     2018-02-01
```

This could also be written like this using the same `library` statements as above:

```
Seq <- function(st, en) as.Date(seq(as.yearmon(st) - 1/12, as.yearmon(en), 1/12))
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  do( data.frame(month = Seq(min(.$date_start), max(.$date_end))) ) %>%
  ungroup
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `dplyr` and `lubridate` is to first `summarise` a `list` of Date objects for each `id` and then `unnest` them to expand them into different rows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(date = list(seq(floor_date(min(date_start),unit = "month") - months(1), 
                   floor_date(max(date_end), unit = "month"), by = "month"))) %>%
  tidyr::unnest()


#   id    date      
#   <fct> <date>    
# 1 a     2012-02-01
# 2 a     2012-03-01
# 3 a     2012-04-01
# 4 a     2012-05-01
# 5 a     2012-06-01
# 6 a     2012-07-01
# 7 a     2012-08-01
# 8 b     2015-05-01
# 9 b     2015-06-01
#10 b     2015-07-01
#11 b     2015-08-01
#12 c     2017-09-01
#13 c     2017-10-01
#14 c     2017-11-01
#15 c     2017-12-01
#16 c     2018-01-01
#17 c     2018-02-01
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, since there are duplicates in `id`, you could group by `row_number` and achieve the same results as below:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(start= floor_date(AddMonths(min(date_start),-1), "month"),end=max(date_end)) %>%
  group_by(rn=row_number()) %>%
  do(data.frame(id=.$id, date=seq(.$start, .$end, by="1 month"))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-rn)
# A tibble: 17 x 2
   id    date      
   <fct> <date>    
 1 a     2012-02-01
 2 a     2012-03-01
 3 a     2012-04-01
 4 a     2012-05-01
 5 a     2012-06-01
 6 a     2012-07-01
 7 a     2012-08-01
 8 b     2015-05-01
 9 b     2015-06-01
10 b     2015-07-01
11 b     2015-08-01
12 c     2017-09-01
13 c     2017-10-01
14 c     2017-11-01
15 c     2017-12-01
16 c     2018-01-01
17 c     2018-02-01
```